# UITableView background color above the UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm adding a `UISearchBar` in the header of the `GroupedTableView`, I have set the background color of the `UITableView` and the `View` in the interface builder to a custom color, but when running the app and scroll down the table view I got the default background color of the `GroupedTableView` above the search bar

[image: Getting default background color about the search bar]

Comment: Have you checked for transparency and vibrancy effects? iOS color correction drives me crazy.

Comment: try to set the tableview background color programmatically in viewDidLoad method..

Comment: @pankaj i did and got the same result

Comment: try this: tableView.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "tableHeaderBackgroundColor")

Answer (score 0):

It is the background color of scroll view. Add content size to scroll view and add layouts to the search bar and table view. This should fix

Comment: Can you explain in more details?

Answer (score -2):

This is default color added to grouped style table view.

set `tableView.backgroundColor` value to the color you want.